Hide SharePoint bar when clicking a button that tries to execute a flow
I have created a list of processes for work where there are several process steps that need to be completed. I have created a button called “Next” that executes a Power Automate flow when clicked. The flow is also running so far, but now I have a problem with a bar that is very annoying (https://ibb.co/NxyVqGZ)
Is there a way to hide the bar so that the flow is executed directly when the button is clicked on?
Thank you very much

There are no screenshot displayed in the answer. Could you attach screenshot again?

Hello Emily, sorry for answering now. I put the Screenshot into the Question section. The flow executed manually when a column called "further" is pushed. Then the Window with the Flow execute shows up. We ask ourself, if its possible to disable the Window and just execute the Flow directly, without pressing the blue Button on the right.
